# Python3: Read quote separated CSV and save it in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a quote-separated CSV with HTML code in it. 
I would like to save the content of the cells in a list of strings. In the past I used this code to read from a CSV-file and save it in a list, but now it returns "IndexError: list index out of range" in the last line. I don't know what to do now. Should I rather try to convert the CSV to an other format or can I just rewrite some of the code?

```
with open("tobetranslated.csv", "r", newline="", encoding="cp1252") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='"', quotechar='|')
    items = [row[0] for row in csv_reader]
```

Here are two entries of tobetranslated.csv:

```
"<div class=""info-holder"" id=""product_bullets_section"">
<p>
VM-2N ist ein Hochleistungs-Verteilverstärker für Composite- oder SDI-Videosignale und unsymmetrisches Stereo-Audio. Das Eingangssignal wird entkoppelt und isoliert, anschließend wird das Signal an zwei identische Ausgänge verteilt.
<span class=""hidden visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-xs-block visible-lg-block"" id=""decora_msg_container"">
<span style=""font-size: small; font-style: italic;"">* DECORA® is a registered trademark of Leviton Manufacturing Co., Inc</span>
</span>
</p>
<ul>
<li>
<span>Hohe Bandbreite - 400 MHz (-3 dB).</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>Desktop-Grösse - Kompakte Bauform, zwei Geräte können mithilfe des optionalen Rackadapters RK-1 in einem 19 Zoll Rack auf 1 HE nebeneinander montiert werden.</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>"
"<div class=""info-holder"" id=""product_bullets_section"">
<p>
VM-8H ist ein Verteilverstärker für HDMI-Signale. Er taktet das Eingangssignal neu, entzerrt es und verteilt es an acht identische Ausgänge.
<span class=""hidden visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-xs-block visible-lg-block"" id=""decora_msg_container"">
<span style=""font-size: small; font-style: italic;"">* DECORA® is a registered trademark of Leviton Manufacturing Co., Inc</span>
</span>
</p>
<ul>
<li>
<span>Max. Datenrate - 6,75 GBit/s (2,25 GBit/s je Grafikkanal).</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>HDTV-kompatibel.</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>HDCP-konform.</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>HDMI-Unterstützung - Deep Color, x.v.Color™, Lip Sync, CEC.</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>3D-Durchleitung.</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>Kramers intelligente EDID-Bearbeitung I-EDIDPro™ - Intelligente EDID Bearbeitungs-Algorithmen sichern eine einfache Plug and Play Installation in HDMI-Anwendungen.</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>Kramers Reclocking - und Entzerrungs Technologie - Baut das Signal neu auf für längere Kabelstrecken.</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>LED-Anzeige eines aktiven Ausgangs.</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>Universal-Netzteil - 100-240 VAC.</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>Standard 19 Zoll Rackeinbau - 1 HE, Rackmontage-Winkel beiliegend.</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>"
```

Comment: HTML code in csvformat? Why and How?

Comment: This file doesn't look good for quote-separated.  Your first term would be `<div class=`, your next would be `info-holder`, then `id=`, `product_bullets_section`, then `><p>VM-2n...`.  Are you sure this is the exact input you want, and that your code has worked with it in the past?
  For the error that you're getting, it's likely that you have a place where the csv comes up with an empty field, effectively a place in your file where you have `"""`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I will going to convert the file to semicolon separeted CSV. 
The reason for such a weird format is my few knowledge about programming. I grabbed the HTML code with Python (urlopen from urllib and request from BeautifulSoup4) and wrote it just like that in a new CSV-file. Excel and LibreCalc weirdly didn't have a problem with that so I guessed it was ok.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the list function to do what you need.

```
with open("tobetranslated.csv", "r", newline="", encoding="cp1252") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='"', quotechar='|')

    items = list(csv_reader)

print(items)
```

Comment: Thank you! I rewrote my CSV-file (appended a semicolon after every </div>") and with your tip I finally have a list of my cells.